# week number of the year by a given date

Tags: angular, typescript, date-pipe

I got the date as follow

```
const today = new Date();
```

now I need to get the week number of the year. How do I get it on the typescript?

I tried `const todayFormated = this.datepipe.transform(today, 'W');` but it is returning the week number of the month not year

Comment: It is not JS. the this is TS

Comment: actually, that's valid EcmaScript6 JS as well. Anyway, I'm tempted to remove the Typescript tag, as the question has not much to do with the TS language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is lowercase `'w'`: `const todayFormated = this.datepipe.transform(today, 'w');`.

From the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe):

> Week of year  w    Numeric: minimum digits    1... 53
>
> Week of month W   Numeric: 1 digit        1... 5